# Ruminant mounts

Tags: mounts

All other factors being equal, would an army with a ruminant mount perform better than an army with horses?

I'm thinking about more efficient digestion, leading to less needed space/time for eating.

Presume that someone has managed to get a deer/moose domesticated into a horse analog. Like if when they domesticated horses in Asia, others domesticated Ruminatia in America.

Would the twin toes of Artiodactyls being more sure-footed also make injuries less common and improve army health overall? Falling from a horse does seem like a relatively common cause of death in ancient nobility.

Comment: *"Falling from a horse does seem like a relatively common cause of death in ancient nobility":* How did nobleman X die? Ate poisonous mushrooms. And nobleman Y? Poisonous mushrooms. Nobleman Z? Also poisonous mushrooms. What about nobleman T? Fell from his horse. Why did he fall from his horse? Well, he did not like mushrooms. (Seriously, falling from a horse is a rare cause of death among both modern and pre-modern noblemen.)

Comment: All other factors being equal, ' a ruminant mount' might work but which Earthly ruminant might yours most resemble? If the answer there is 'none; this if fiction' then write if for all you're worth

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem with the ruminant foregut-fermenting digestive system is that it is very good at dealing with low-quality food, like grass.  However, it is less good at dealing with high-quality food like fruit.  In fact, such high-quality food can cause runaway microbial growth in the rumen that the imbalance can be fatal.  Cattle that eat lots of fruit must be surgically treated to remove the fruit in order to save their lives.

Hindgut fermenters like horses can eat all the fruit they want.  Their digestive system removes the excess sugars from their feed before it gets to their fermentation apparatus.

So, what does this have to do with warfare and riding (or transport) animals?  When you use animals in war, you need them to be able to work for long periods, and not have to let them stand around grazing for hours, so you have to carry feed for your animals.  When it comes to carrying feed, feed with the highest-possible energy density per kilogram is best, as it takes less transport to transport the transport's feed, leaving more transport for war-fighting material or combatants.

You can give a horse a nose-bag filled with high-quality food while it's on the march, and it'll be happy.  If you do that with a cow, you could kill it.  That means that if you're employing foregut fermenters, you need to carry lower-quality food, or you have to let them graze more... and the necessities of war may not permit the time for grazing, or bring your ruminants to a place where there is sufficient pasture for them to graze upon.  Thus we get back to carrying fodder.  Would you rather transport relatively small amounts of oats or fruit, or lots of hay or silage?  With hindgut fermenters, you can cart around smaller amounts of high-quality fodder if it's available.  With foregut fermenters, you *have* to cart around lower-quality fodder or risk your animals dying.

"But armies used lots of cattle!" some might say.  *As transport* is the answer.  When you're dealing with logistics, its a matter of *continuity* of supply.  If you're transporting non-perishables, it doesn't really matter how long it takes for the supplies to arrive.  Armies weren't typically supplied with much in the way of perishables... they tend to perish.  Of course, meat on the hoof isn't perishable until it dies and you butcher it for dinner.

As I said to Kilisi in a comment, if you had a horse and a ruminant called an esroh that was functionally identical to a horse in *all* ways *except* that it was a ruminant, the horse would *still* be the preferred animal to carry combatants into battle.  Horses can eat richer fodder, which places less burden on logistics.  That means that a horse can operate further from supply for longer periods than an esroh, because horse riders can carry a smaller amount of rich fodder that would kill esrohs.  Esrohs would need to spend longer grazing, or require their nose-bags filled with fodder more often.  Esrohs fed too-high-quality fodder would be more prone to illness or death, while a horse wouldn't care.

When it doesn't matter that esrohs eat lower-quality food than horses, such as in logistical supply chains, where the esrohs can be allowed to graze overnight, *that* is where they would be best used.  Not in battle, or near the front lines where speed is desired, but in the rear areas, where staying power and the ability to consume lower-quality fodder is more desirable.

Comment: So what your saying is under adhoc conditions the esroh would do better just eating what's available,  but an army that's got there shit together can do more with a horse. Am I interpreting you correctly?

Comment: @tomBebop You need to be careful what you feed a ruminant.  You don't need to be so careful with a horse.  Humans and horses can eat high-energy foods quickly, and then work for a long time.  Ruminants will die if you fed them the same food, because it's too rich... but they can survive on crap that would starve even a horse.  Because horses can eat rich food, they can live longer on a bag of fodder suitable for them than a cow can live on a bag of suitable food the same size.  So, yes, an army with its shit together can do more with horses *in battle* and ruminants as logistical support.

Answer (score 3):

Digestion wouldn't make much difference. Many armies had no issues travelling and feeding both ruminants and horses at the same time. Thats more about what feed is available in the locale.

But if you could train these animals to the same extent as horses then they'd be valuable fighting machines. Many have horns and reinforced skulls designed to take impacts. So a charge could be extremely devastating if you weaponised the horns with some sharp bits. They used to put [huge swords on elephant tusks](https://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection/search/679021) for instance. You could do something similar.

[image: Mughal tusk sword]

Mughal Tusk Sword

Comment: @MontyWild armies routinely took whole herds of ruminants with them... all armies deal with logistics as a matter of course

Comment: @MontyWild you're wrong, again, it's been done many times and they just need to move as fast as the infantry most of the time. Armies aren't battling usually

Answer (score 1):

i dont think a different digestive system would really make things all the much better, and as someone else said ruminants cannot have a bunch of food at once or theyll get sick

as someone who works with both ruminants and horses, no ruminants are really clumsy and stupid, theyre harder to train too because they lack intelligence

im mostly talking abt sheep here, i dont know abt others as much

sheep struggle with problem solving and constantly get themselves stuck fences or water troughs and the like (sometimes die drom trying get themselves unstuck), they miss alot of cues we give them when trying to get them somewhere or give them food. they are adamant about not receiving human help unless theyre raised by humans. they will do anything for food too, including risking the saftey of themselves and others. they dont really have any observation skills besides "how to find food". theyre also really really lazy and will avoid as much physical activity as possible.

deer also appear to behave similarly besides the fact they seem less clumsy and waaayyy more skittish

goats seem quire a bit smarter than both and are much more agile, plus they can climb things waaayyy better than equines, so a large version of a goat might be a good calvary option

cows kinda seem like a kinder versions of sheep with maybe a wee bit more intelligence

horses meanwhile vary in coordination but most are very agile. horses are LEAGUES above sheep in intelligence, they are easily trainable, good at problem solving, and even good at tricking humans. they enjoy being put to work because its entertaining and makes them think, but theyre also looking for every opportunity they can get to do the bare minimum. so they will play little games with their handlers to try and get away with things. however when out in the fields they really like to run around lol. they know mutiple words instead of just their name unlike sheep. and they are also crazy at reading body language, they read everyone like children's books. they pick up on every little thing someone is doing, even things that someone might not realize theyre doing. they are food motivated however they also are very caring about others unlike sheep. some are even nice other creatures that they dont care much about or even creatures that hurt them. they feel responsible for their handlers and will make sure they dont get severely hurt. even if the horse is typically a total jerk towards others, their goal typically isnt to severely harm others, its just all for s**ts and giggles. theyre also very observant of their surroundings too, sometimes a bit too observant lol.

this isnt only me who says this people who work with these animals say the same things abt them, and those words are not solely based off of personal experience, but also what others say abt them, including experts

Answer (score -2):

**It's difficult to judge, there having been no army that used ruminant animals as primary cavalry... but that might prove the point**

Considering there are probably a thousand times the number of deer/elk/moose on Earth compared to horses, you'd think that if they were as or more valuable, they'd have been adopted for war and horses used for food. But....

> Ruminants are herbivorous grazing or browsing artiodactyls belonging to the suborder Ruminantia that are able to acquire nutrients from plant-based food by fermenting it in a specialized stomach prior to digestion, principally through microbial actions. The process, which takes place in the front part of the digestive system and therefore is called foregut fermentation, typically requires the fermented ingesta (known as cud) to be regurgitated and chewed again. The process of rechewing the cud to further break down plant matter and stimulate digestion is called rumination. The word "ruminant" comes from the Latin ruminare, which means "to chew over again".
>
> The roughly 200 species of ruminants include both domestic and wild species. Ruminating mammals include cattle, all domesticated and wild bovines, goats, sheep, giraffes, deer, gazelles, and antelopes. ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruminant))

While militaries throughout history have tried to use all kinds of animals during war, the fact that no military that I'm aware of replaced the horse as primary cavalry with another animal with one exception (the elephant, also non-ruminant) is better than average proof that ruminant animals would be inferior to, specifically, horses.

Nature has a few things that are individually quite amazing. Water, for instance, is simply amazing. Horses, IMO, fall into the amazing category. They have an excellent balance of speed, strength, agility, intelligence, domestication, maintenance, etc. They're just so honking *useful...* and it's difficult to imagine any one animal that can do all that they can do.

Have you seen those skinny legs on deer, elk, and antelope? Put a heavy load on them and I suspect you'll discover they injure faster than a horse's legs will. While it's somewhat common to sling a slain deer over a horse to pack it out, I'm having trouble imagining slinging a slain horse over a deer for the same purpose. I'm having trouble seeing it even with elk or moose. Don't try it with a moose. Nothing says "mean" like a pissed-off moose.

Have you seen the majestic bulk of cattle? Horses can gallop circles around them.

Granted, a goat can eat pretty much *anything...* but don't let all those stomachs fool you. Goats and horses eat basically the same thing. So there's no actual maintenance benefit to ruminating animals. In fact, since the cud must be regurgitated, rechewed, and reswallowed, it might be a negative. I haven't done the research, but it might take longer for the animal to be ready for battle.

And having looked into the eyes of a few of these animals, it is my uneducated opinion that most have the attention span of a gnat compared to horses who, I seriously suspect, think that all humans are funny at best, idiots at worst, and therefore it's simple charity that they help us out whenever they can.

Except for the first time when it's just as simply necessary to remind humans that they're only allowed to believe they're in charge. Don't believe me? Ask the rider who was a second away from getting out of the rodeo arena when 1500 lbs of horse decided to remind him of who's in charge. Bulls... they're just mindless beasts. It takes a horse to turn such an educational moment into pure artistry.

So, no, ruminating species weren't and wouldn't be superior to traditional cavalry.

**But who cares?**

Why are you asking your question? Would you choose to not use ruminating species as primary cavalry in your story based on a negative response? Don't do that! The only practical reason someone might think it's funny to ride into battle on an antelope is that it's so darn uncommon. We'd look sideways at it like we do [Nicki Minaj's lamborghini](https://s.yimg.com/os/en-US/blogs/motoramic/184711130.jpg). If we saw dozens of those <s>awful</s> pink lambos on the road every day, we wouldn't think twice about it.

My point is, use the information you learn here to enhance your story. Every animal has pros and cons — and the cons are as valuable for telling a cool story as the pros.

Go ahead and use ruminating animals as primary cavalry!

Comment: There *is* a difference, in two words: Food quality.  Horses can eat high-quality food.  Cattle can't.... and that food needs to be carried...

Comment: Cows are designed to be eaten, horses for drafting. And yes, I said designed. They were selectively bred for thousands of years to do the jobs they have now. Horses are smart because we need them to do work, cows are stupid because we don't want them getting any ideas. There are cultures that switch it up a bit (case in point, draft oxen exist), but the vast majority of cultures use the horse as a draft animal and the cow as a food animal

Comment: @MontyWild As in... armies must carry food for horses? I've been around them too much to believe that. Or are they carrying lower quality food? That doesn't make sense, either, since in the field food quality isn't predictable. What's your point? Because your comment appears to be supporting my answer.

Comment: @NoName I'm not saying you're wrong, but OK... are you supporting my answer, which says that (among other animals) cows won't replace horses?

Comment: Consider what might happen in a total war scenario if fields are burned or poisoned to deny an advancing enemy fodder for their animals.  Consider a party of mounted raiders, who must travel quickly through unfriendly territory, and can't afford to stop, who must either limit the time they stay in enemy territory or bring food for man and beast.  In these scenarios, the highest quality food practical is going to be neccesary.  If the beasts are ruminants, the necessarily lower-quality food is going to become a limitation.

Comment: @MontyWild Situation #1: all food must be carted regardless of animal type. Situation #2: depending on the terrain, an elk might be more providential than a horse for living off the land. We might be in violent agreement. My answer is that ruminants won't solve the problem for a variety of reasons - we appear only to disagree with my statement, "goats and horses eat basically the same thing." I suspect that from the U.S. Civil War backwards few armies carried substantial fodder for the horses, electing instead to live off the land. Could be wrong, though.

Comment: My point is that the reason cows don't work is because they were bred for different things than horses. Oxen may have been good for plowing and heavy loads (and indeed were the only choice until a proper horse yoke was developed), but horses were always preferred for cavalry and our breeding efforts only exaggerated that. Everything that makes a horse better - except maybe the stomach - was bred into place by us, upto and including the heft of a plow horse. And note that horses eventually replaced oxen there too.

Comment: But that, of course, begs the question of why our ancestors went with the horse rather than the cow in the first place, and the only things that matter are the stuff that was there before we started mucking around in their business - the stomach, the horns and the bone structure, particularly the shoulders

Comment: @NoName That's a good point, but one would assume in the OP's world that the ruminant beast used to replace horses for cavalry would have been bred for that purposes. The actions of human history don't bind the OP. You correctly bring up the issue, what is it about cows *intrinsically* that would make them unsuitable? I suspect that at this point you and I are also in violent agreement.